# Hyperledger Fabric getState doesn't return all data

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, getstate

We are trying to retrieve data from Hyperledger Fabric using getState method. We have around 500000 objects stored in fabric's repository each object is of around 100kb size. When executing getState method it is not able to retrieve all the data. We are hardly getting 20% of data only being returned by getState method. Is there any limit on data size that can be retrieved while using getState method in hyperledger fabric. How can we improve the current situation.

Comment: Which statedb are you using

Answer (score 0):

It is because default totalQueryLimit of peer is 10000. Set that Environment Variable in
peer as
`CORE_LEDGER_STATE_TOTALQUERYLIMIT = 50000`